# UDP Multicast doesn't work in 2 different PCs

Tags: java, server, udp, client, multicast

I prepared a multicast client-server. It works on the same computer, but when I use two different PCs none of them seems to receive anything.
I disabled the firewall in both computers.

Here is the code:

Server:

```
public void send(byte[] sendThis) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            DatagramSocket socket;
            InetAddress group;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    socket = new DatagramSocket();
                    group = InetAddress.getByName("230.0.0.0");
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(sendThis, sendThis.length, group, 4446);
                    socket.send(packet);
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
```

Client:

```
public byte[] receive() {
            MulticastSocket socket = null;
            byte[] buf = new byte[2000];
            byte[] received = new byte[2000];
            try {
                socket = new MulticastSocket(4447);
                InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("230.0.0.0");
                socket.joinGroup(group);
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                socket.receive(packet);
                // received = packet.getData();
                received = new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength()).getBytes();
                socket.leaveGroup(group);
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return received;
        }
```

The ports are changed in the other machine (server 4447, client 4446)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the AP needs a little configuration change: IGMP (Internet Group Management Protocol) should be enabled.

Some AP don't support this feature (mine doesn't), so I had to try it in a different network.